# Using cmbright in XeLaTex for Math and Text

Tags: fonts, xetex

I would like to use XeTex and use a Sans Serif font for Math and Text. When I use `cmbright` I always get warning messages.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmbright}       %CMU Bright for math
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    ]

\begin{document}
 % I get 2 warnings:
 % Warning: cmbright.sty
 % LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined (Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 144.
 % Warning: root.tex
 % LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The warnings are harmless.

Comment: Ok. They might be harmless but is there a way to define the missing font shape by myself? So that I can get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the warnings by changing the loading order of the packages and giving your sans font the family name used by cmbright.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    NFSSFamily=cmbr
    ]   

\usepackage{cmbright}       %CMU Bright for math

% as cmbright sets \ttdefault to cmtl either:
%\setmonofont{whatever}[NFSSFamily=cmtl]
% or
%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} 

\begin{document}
abc $a=b$
\end{document}
```

But it would naturally simpler if cmbright wouldn't issue a `\normalfont` command. It looks quite useless.