# One font for math, another for text

Tags: fonts, fontspec, windows

I would like to have

- **Calibri** for **text**, and
- **CM Bright** for **math**.

Is this possible?

My own attempt was to override the CM Bright text font using `fontspec` with the `no-math` option. However this does not work. Does anybody have an idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}
Test $test\int\xi$
\end{document}
```

[This is Windows. For Linux include the fonts in the directory and use `\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont=calibriz.ttf, BoldFont=calibrib.ttf, ItalicFont=calibrii.ttf]{calibri.ttf}`]

Comment: I had a similar question about how to correctly set CM Bright while using `fontspec`. Maybe the answer there also helps you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358418/using-cmbright-in-xelatex-for-math-and-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cmbright` package wrongly does `\normalfont` at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}

% fix the error in cmbright.sty that executes \normalfont
\let\latexnormalfont\normalfont
\let\normalfont\relax
% load cmbright
\usepackage{cmbright}
% restore the meaning of \normalfont
\let\normalfont\latexnormalfont

% restore the standard fonts for text
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Futura} % I don't have Calibri

\begin{document}

Test $test\int\xi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

However, I am still not sure **why** and if this is **the correct way** (does this work for all types of fonts?).