# Is it possible to use fonts of different families for regular text and math formulae?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, math-fonts, noto

I recently found out how to use Google Noto fonts for regular text in LaTeX documents. It is my belief that they strain my eyes much less when on-screen than CM fonts do (it is probably the opposite for printed documents, though).

Here is my pet document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}
\else
\usepackage{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\color{gray}
$$\sin^{n + 1} x+1 + \frac{x}{\exp{y}} \cdot \vec{S}$$
    Test!
$$\sqrt{\cosh^2(\vartheta + 1) + \hat{Q}} $$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```

And pdf-output thereof

[image]

The text looks great, but I would prefer the names of functions in formulae to remain rendered with CM-fonts. Can it be done?

P. S. I am looking for a solution that could be applied to all formulae, rather than putting some commands specifying the font to use before every single one of them.

Comment: `[nomath]` option for fontspec package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Small correction: [nomath] gives error, but [no-math] does work as desired. Thank you very much!

Comment: oops:-) .......

Comment: BTW: [Don't use `$$…$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: @cabohah Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Crosslink: Same answer but maybe different question:
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551812)
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519233)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97299)
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10488)
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370584)