# xelatex & libertine: \renewcommand\ttdefault no longer works

Tags: xetex, fontspec, libertine

This MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}

\begin{document}
foo \texttt{bar}
\end{document}
```

previously (say, about one year ago) typeset `bar` with lmtt if processed with XeLaTeX.  It no longer does.  Instead, a member of the Libertine font family gets used.  Obviously, changing `\ttdefault` gets ignored.  Why?

Note that processing with pdflatex delivers the expected Latin Modern font.

Used packages (from TeXLive SVN rev 52404, 2019-10-16)

- LateX2e 2019-10-01
- fontspec 2019-10-14
- libertine 2019-02-27

[I regenerated all formats with `fmtutil-usr --all`.]

[image: xelatex output]

Comment: What's the reason for not doing `\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine}`?

Comment: Quite simple: I wasn't aware of that option :-)  Now I know, thanks.  However, the OP persists, as far as I can see.

Comment: If I do `\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine}` and remove `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}`, I get Latin Modern Mono. Don't you?

Comment: Yes, I do.  However, the old way no longer works, see the answers in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358418/using-cmbright-in-xelatex-for-math-and-text or https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/24994.html, for example.  Both solutions give `\renewcommand\ttdefault...` as a possibility – and as mentioned above, it *did* work previously.

Comment: Note that this is unrelated to `libertine.sty` and also happens with `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}`.

Comment: Thanks, Ralf, I guessed that but didn't have time to investigate it more closely.

Comment: How is it possible to have the `2019-10-14` version of `fontspec`? The newest release was `v2.7c (2019/03/15)`.

Comment: You are right.  I mixed it up with the version number of the first loaded package (`xparse.sty`).

Answer (score 3):

### 2019/10/18 update

Will clarified this issue to be an oversight of `fontspec` [in his comment](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/386#issuecomment-543443021). I propose the following **temporary patch** before the next release of `fontspec`. The patch works under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}

% Temporary patch
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{fontspec}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily{%
      \fontencoding{\csname g__fontspec_nfss_enc_tl\endcsname}%
      \fontfamily{\ttdefault}%
      \selectfont
    }%
  }{%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo \texttt{bar}
\end{document}
```

Warning: This patch depends on `fontspec`’s private variable `\g_@@_nfss_enc_tl` and thus could stop working with newer releases of `fontspec`.

---

### Original answer

Running the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}

\begin{document}
foo \texttt{bar}
\end{document}
```

with [`fontspec` 2016/01/30 v2.5](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/releases/tag/v2.5), I got

[image: foo bar]

But with [`fontspec` 2017/02/12 v2.6](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/releases/tag/v2.6) or later, I got

[image: foo bar]

---

The package `libertine` calls `fontspec` internally when running on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Since `fontspec` v2.6, the implementation of `\setmonofont` was changed. With the newer releases, after issuing `\setmonofont{<Foo>}`, `fontspec` will redefine `\ttfamily` to always use the font family `<Foo>` instead of the ones by `\ttdefault`.

User level redefinition of `\ttdefault` is never good syntax IMHO. I recommend using higher level redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
% For XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
foo \texttt{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What was the reason for this change in fontspec?  I consider it quite bad, since (a) it is incompatible to previous versions, and (b) it is incompatible to other TeX engines.  In other words, it breaks zillions of documents, because the solution you are tagging as having 'never good syntax' was standard for many years, as shown in the links I gave.

Comment: By the way, using `\setmonofont` makes the document uncompilable with pdflatex...

Comment: @lemzwerg “because the solution you are tagging as having 'never good syntax' was standard for many years, as shown in the links I gave” I disagree. Just because a solution was provided to the public decades ago does not make it standard in any regards. The font package, `libertine` in this case, should be responsible for providing an option to configure your mono-spaced family (which it does). I was simply explaining why these hacks from years ago stopped working.

Comment: Ok, let's agree to disagree.  However, the two backward incompatibilities are something that can't be discussed away.  Additionally, it's not mentioned in fontspec's `README.md` file that this (mis)feature no longer works.

Honestly, I consider the whole issue as something that accidentally happened while Will reorganized and simplified the fontspec code, especially if you read the relevant commit messages.

Comment: @lemzwerg Well, if you use `fontspec` for your documents, then you must use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and not pdfLaTeX. And `fontspec` never said “if you want to set up mono-spaced family, then you could redefine `\ttdefault` by looking at the NFSS specification and do something like `\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}`”. Instead, `fontspec` said “use `\setmonofont` to set up your mono-spaced family”.

Comment: @lemzwerg When you want cross compatibility under different engines, but don’t want to think about font encodings (T1 or TU) or font formats (TFM-based or OpenType), you would use a *font package* to take care of everything. This is why I am saying it’s `libertine`’s job to provide flexible configuration. It is not `fontspec`’s job to think about pdfLaTeX. As `egreg` suggests, you can always just use `\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine}`.

Comment: Fair point regarding direct use of the `fontspec` package.  However, I still want to know why `fontspec` provides `\ttdefault` at all if it has no relevance.  Regarding the 'bad hack', have a look into LaTeX2e's `fntguide.pdf`, section 2.4, which explicitly mentions manipulation of `\ttdefault` and friends. – I value maintaining of backward compatibility (even if unintentional) as a very high goal.  If it is no longer given, it should at least be documented.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/386

Comment: If you need to use legacy Type 1 fonts, you can load `libertine-type1` or `libertinus-type1` rather than `libertine`. This is an inferior solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works again with fontspec version 2.7d, released 2019-10-19.

Comment: For my humble opinion this is a comment.

Comment: Hmm.  It's not clear to me how to better answer my own question.  The OP describes a bug, which has been fixed with the just released fontspec version.  Maybe the question should be removed altogether?