# beamer + cmbright + xelatex incompatible?

Tags: beamer, xetex

I would like to use CM Bright for formulas in Beamer slides with XeLaTeX.

Using CM Bright with pdfLaTeX is straightforward. The code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Formula: \(F = o^r \mu_l^a\)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: pdflatex]

However, the same code compiled with XeLaTeX gives

[image: xelatex]

The greek µ is still replaced by the CM Bright version, but the latin letters are all CM Roman.

Now this looks like there is an incompatibility between `cmbright` and XeLaTeX. However, if I do the same thing as an `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
Formula: \(F = o^r \mu_l^a\)
\end{document}
```

and compile with XeLaTeX, I get

[image: article]

The text font is CM Roman, but the formula is consistently CM Bright. (See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358621/38399).)

So there appears to be a specific incompatibility of `beamer` + `cmbright` + `xelatex`.

Why is that so, and is there a way around it?

PS: Why XeLaTeX? Because I'm planning to use an OpenType font for text. Off topic, but if someone has a recommendation which OpenType sans serif font goes well with CM Bright, tell me!

Comment: Try loading the font as in the the question you linked to. This will produce the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the fonts as in the linked question, you get the desired output.

XeLaTeX needs OpenType or TrueType fonts rather than the Type1 fonts used by pdfLaTeX. So to use CMBright with XeLaTeX for text, you need to load the OpenType version of the font. But there isn't an OpenType version of the math fonts, so we first load the OpenType font as the sans serif font with the `no-math` option to suppress an changes `fontspec` might make to the math setup.

Then we load the `cmbright` package which will effectively load the math font.  You can change the sans font again after loading `cmbright`, but this will not really work effectively, since even in math you will end up with a mixture of CMBright and whatever font you subsequently set, which will not look good.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    NFSSFamily=cmbr
    ]   

\usepackage{cmbright}       %CMU Bright for math
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Formula: \(F = o^r \mu_l^a\)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! I omitted those lines because I didn't want to specify a `sansfont` (yet). I guess it's the `no-math` option? But I didn't load `fontspec`, so how can it meddle with the fonts?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I accepted your answer too soon. Yes, the code from the linked answer works. However, it only works if I use `\setsansfont` for CM Bright, too. It doesn't work for example with `\setsansfont{Noto Sans}`. And the answer does not explain why this problem occurs, and which part(s) exactly of the code circumvent it. `no-math` and `professionalfonts` don't seem to be sufficient. What does `\setsansfont` have to do with getting a math font working?

Comment: @A.Donda I've added some more explanation. You can't really do what you want to do, since the math part of CMBright will use both the sans font and the CMBright math characters in math, so you will always get a mixture unless you make CMBright the sans font.

Comment: Thanks, now it becomes clearer. I did some experiments, and I found that a) `professionalfonts` doesn't make a difference b) `no-math` doesn't make a difference, and c) even `\usepackage{cmbright}` doesn't make a difference. I get the exact same result if I my preamble is `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{cmunb}[Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*mr,ItalicFont=*mo,BoldFont=*sr,BoldItalicFont=*so,NFSSFamily=cmbr]`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with that, or will I run into math problems down the line? Maybe the whole idea of using CM Bright for math with xelatex is just misguided?

Comment: @A.Donda  Not sure about the professional fonts, which I added just in case, but if you don't load `cmbright` you will not get `cmbright` math, and you want to load the OpenType font with `no-math`. Compare the μ with and without loading the package. They are not the same. For some, the whole idea of sans math is misguided... :) But doing it as I show is at least a consistent solution.

Comment: You are right, `cmbright` does change the greek characters. Misguided, maybe, I just doubt that my otherwise favorite TeX Gyre Pagella Math is suited for digital projection. Ok, so you are saying that with this code, `\setsansfont{cmunb}` + `cmbright`, I can expect consistent (if misguided) sans math?

Comment: The only alternative, Fira Math, is imho pretty horrible. The letters are awkward, and the spacing is off.

Comment: @A.Donda Yes, the solution will get you consistent sans math. I'm not a mathematician, but I use some math  and I often use a serifed font for presentations. I like Cambria which also has an OpenType Math font, although it's not a free font (but it's likely you have a copy). See [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098) for lots of other options.